# Submit app for Review

Tags: appexchange, security-review

[image: Here is screenshot of error]I want to publish my app on appexchange in order to do so i need to review, So while submitting my for review i am getting error at step 5. salesforce is asking for production/sandbox credentials. I tried with my developer credentials but its throwing error which i have attached.
I have gone through requirement for publishing from that i came to know that i need full copy sandbox which i will be getting with unlimited or enterprise edition(need to demand explicitly). I don't have any of these edition copy. So is there any other solution to this so my investment be reduced?
Is my knowledge correct, Please improve if i am wrong anywhere?

Comment: You should be able to use your developer credentials. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: pardy i have added image pls come back to me

Answer (score 0):

It requires a partnerforce login. You can find detailed steps in below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout